# How to pass schemas to children using @fastify/autoload?

Tags: node.js, schema, autoload, fastify

I have a folder for routes, what has different classes. Each class has it's own `index.ts` and `schemas.ts`.

**Folder structure:**

```
├───routes
│   │   ├───db
│   │   │   ├───param1
|   │   │   │   └─index.ts (but I want also the db's schemas to be available)
|   │   │   │   └─schemas.ts
│   │   │   └───param2
│   │   │   └─index.ts
│   │   │   └─schemas.ts
```

Is there a way to pass these schemas to subdirectories (endpoints with params) without breaking the general encapsulation?

Currently it's working this way, schemas loaded first to the app context, then the routes:

```
await app.register(autoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'routes'),
    encapsulate: false,
    indexPattern: /schema/,
  });

await app.register(autoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'routes'),
    ignoreFilter: (path) => path.includes('schema'),
    routeParams: true,
  });
```